# Maven - from where is "Release-Name" field data retrieved while creating MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, maven, plugins, war, manifest.mf

We are using Jenkins maven plugin for building and deploying war applications. In the jenkinsfile we have the command (I removed the list of profiles for the sake of simplicity):

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare -P<profiles> -U -DautoVersionSubmodules="true" -Darguments="-T 1C -DskipTests=true" -V --batch-mode --errors
```

The built war artifact has MANIFEST.MF file with field Release-Name set to main.

> Release-Name: main

In the parent pom.xml there are some extra settings for customize MANIFEST.MF but it seems to me that "Release-Name" is added by default because it is not listed below:

```
<manifestEntries>
   <Version>${project.version}</Version>
   <Revision-Number>${buildNumber}</Revision-Number>
   <Branch>${GIT_BRANCH}</Branch>
   <Local-Branch>${scmBranch}</Local-Branch>
</manifestEntries>
```

So I tried to look into the maven release plugin source code from this [repository](https://github.com/apache/maven-release) but I couldn't find anything helpful.
Then the main question is how the field "Release-Name" is filled because I'd like to change it into some more meaningful value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as it turned out, was in another module of the project, which was downloaded from remote repository, while building the entire artifact. In this extra module, there was a definition in pom used to set the value of Release-Name in the manifestEntries section.

```
<Release-Name>${releaseName}</Release-Name>
```